# In SQL how to calculate days in a year based on a start date and the number of days lapsed

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-arithmetic

What would be the SQL to calculate the number of days in each year if I had a start date and the number of days that have lapsed?

For example, the date (ymd) 2013-01-01 and the days lapsed is 1000.

I would like the result to look like this

2013 = 365

2014 = 365

2015 = 270

Can this be written as a function like `datediff`?

I have tried using a calendar table, but of course, linking to this just gives me 2013 = 1000

My calendar table looks like this.

```
DATE_ID  | DATE       | CALENDAR_YEAR | FINANCIAL_YEAR
-----------------------------------------------
20130101 | 2013-01-01 | 2013          | 2013/14
```

This is what i have tried.

> SELECT
>
> D.FISCAL_YEAR, SUM([DAYS]) AS NUMBER_OF_DAYS
>
> FROM [dbo].[FACT] F
>
> LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DIM_DATE] D ON D.DATE_ID = F.DATE_ID
>
> GROUP BY
>
> D.FISCAL_YEAR

The result for this is.

```
FISCAL_YEAR | NUMBER_OF_DAYS
----------------------------
2013/14     |2820 
2014/15     |6635 
2015/16     |2409
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried with your calendar table. I would expect adding a GROUP BY will provide the results you want.

Comment: Do you actually need the results for each individual year in a query, or a function that you supply one single year to which gives one single number as the result? The latter can be done more efficiently than the former.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to calculate the *day-of-the-year* in the final year, and the total number of days in years prior? Also, do you realise that 2014 was a leap year (and thus had 366 days)?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I think the tally table maybe the way to go. When joining to the calendar table, obviously the join is made on the date, which then returns whichever column you've selected as the grouping. In this case Fiscal Year. but all this ends up doing, is giving the number of days assigned to the Fiscal year of the start date. What I want to happen is that it takes the start date and then works out how many days in each year is available before moving ot the next and then the next, as opposed to lumping it against the start date fiscal year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally build a tally table to do this. Once you build that, you can easly get every date and count the number of days in each year:

```
DECLARE @YMD date = '20130101',
        @Lapsed int = 1000;

--Build a Tally table
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4), --10,000 should be enough
--Build the dates table
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @YMD) AS CalendarDate
    FROM Tally T
    WHERE T.I <= @Lapsed - 1)
--And count the days
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate) AS Year,
       COUNT(CalendarDate) AS Days
FROM Dates D
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate);
```

As a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CountDays (@YMD date, @Lapsed int)
RETURNS table 
AS RETURN

    --Build a Tally table
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4), --10,000 should be enough
    --Build the dates table
    Dates AS(
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @YMD) AS CalendarDate
        FROM Tally T
        WHERE T.I <= @Lapsed - 1)
    --And count the days
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate) AS Year,
           COUNT(CalendarDate) AS Days
    FROM Dates D
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate);

GO

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('20130101',1000),
            ('20150501',755))V(YMD, Lapsed)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.CountDays(V.YMD,V.Lapsed) CD;
```

Comment: Amazingly quick response, i will try this now. Would this be suitable for a table with possibly millions of rows? So ideally I would want to sum the number of days for every row selected in the where clause.

Comment: A tally table is an incredibly fast method, @SQL_Novice. Unlike an rCTE it's not recursive. This specific one will handle up to a a value of 10,000 for @Lapsed (over 27 years), but if you do need a larger range just add `N` more times in `Tally`. Yes can easily translate this against a table, yes, and it'll still be fast; but I can't see your table so i can't show you how you'd do that.

Comment: Sorry, i am really new to SQL so apologies for the really silly question. I can see the variables YMD and Lapsed. So I understand how it works if i parse in individual dates and days. But how would this be used in a situation where possibly millions of dates and days will be parsed into this? Can it be converted into a function?

Comment: Amazing this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. I'll need to go and study your wizardry to fully understand what is happening, but this produces the results i need.

Comment: Would you always have to use CROSS APPLY, or could you simply parse in the columns from the table in question. i.e. SELECT 

dbo.CountDays(DATE,DAYS) CD

FROM FACT

Comment: You can't reference a table-value function like a Scalar function @SQL_Novice, no.

Comment: Can this be converted to a scalar function?

Comment: @SQL_Novice no, because a scalar function can only return a scalar value. Also, unless you're using SQl Server 2019, and the inline scalar function syntax I recommend against Scalar functions. They (multi line scalar functions) are often significantly slower than an **inline** table-vakue function

Comment: Thank you, this has been most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select v.d, 1000 - datediff(day, v.d, dateadd(year, 1, v.d)) as days
      from (values (datefromparts(2013, 1, 1))) v(d)
      union all
      select dateadd(year, 1, d), days - datediff(day, d, dateadd(year, 1, d)) 
      from dates
      where days > 0
     )
select d,
       (case when days > 0 then datediff(day, d, dateadd(year, 1, d))
             else datediff(day, d, dateadd(year, 1, d)) + days
        end)
from dates;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5ba52e0662c10c0bb58e20a62e898ddd) is a db<>fiddle.